# How to use Match (and replace) function when the source you are matching with is a dynamic (textbox) value (in userforms)?

Tags: excel, vba

I am extremely new to vba code/coding of any sort, and am trying to develop a loaning system for equipment within my discipline using excel sheets and forms.

Essentially, I want a cmdbutton_click to update the availability status of the specific piece of equipment to "On Loan" within the inventory list spreadsheet. The problem I am having however, is with the fact that the form user will enter the ItemID (number) which obviously will always be different. The item ID is the value of which I am looking to use the Match function with.

I have tried to refer to the form's ItemID text box using the match function, but it does not work whatsoever - I understand this is probably completely incorrect.

`Set ws2 = Worksheets("MajorInventoryList")
ws2.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(me.txtID.value), 10) = "On Loan"`

This brings about the Compile error: 'Argument not optional'

Is there any way to ameliorate this?

Comment: You should use `Range.Find` instead of Match.

Comment: For in your code `Match` takes more than 1 argument, you are only passing the word to match, not the range in which you need to search it.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense. How would I use the RangeFind function in my case? Sorry if a stupid question.

Comment: `Set fnd = ws2.UsedRange.Find(Me.txtID.Value)` this will give you an Range Object. then you can use `fnd.Value = "On Loan"`  with if condition to set it You can also replace UsedRange with a Defined Range if you want to search in a particular column or row

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but will this work if the ItemID (Column A) is the 'Find' value and Availability Status (Column J) is the targeted corresponding cell to update?

Comment: No .. In that case you will have to use `ws2.Cells("J" & fnd.row).value = "On Loan"`.. Second line to be replaced with this

Comment: Is this to be used within an IF condition, as mentioned above or? I'm still not having any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Find` like this:

```
Set ws2 = Worksheets("MajorInventoryList")

Set fnd = ws2.Range("A:A").Find(Me.txtID.Value)

If Not fnd Is Nothing Then ws2.Cells(fnd.Row,10).Value = "On Loan"
```

This will look for Text Input in Column A and if found, will place "On Loan" in column J of that row in which the value exists.

Comment: I am still getting a run time error '5': 'invalid procedure call or argument' with regards to `ws2.Cells("J" & fnd.Row).Value = "On Loan"`

Comment: Okay , Use the Edited one

Comment: @JoelMcWilliam , I have tested it now, it's Working

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help and patience!